# How to get the assembly equivalent of CPP file having only templates

Tags: c++, templates, assembly

I have a C++ file which has only template methods of a template class.  I tried to compile that with -S option.

It is generating the .s file, but it doesn't have any assembly code in it - for example:

```
.section        ".text",#alloc,#execinstr

.file   "eac_slist.C"
.xstabs ".stab.index","V=9.0;DBG_GEN=5.0.8;dm;cd;backend;ptf;ptx;ptk;ptr/vobs/eam;s;;P;R=5.8<<Sun C++ 5.8 2005/10/13 (ccfe)>>;A=2",60,0,0,0
.xstabs ".stab.index","/vobs/ossrc_3pp/freeware/studio11/SUNWspro/prod/bin/CC -I. -S  -xs  eac_slist.C",52,0,0,0
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want asm generated for the template?  This will help direct our answers.

Comment: I have a core dump file in that area. To analyze core dump we use mdb. So it will be help full if i get the assembly code to analyze the core dump

Comment: The assembly can be found (in machine code form) in the core or your original program.  Your debugger should be able to display this as assembly for you.

Comment: From the core we will get the method where it core dumped and assembly too. We will find out the exact place of core dump in the code(i.e. which line it dumped) by matching the assembly code of the core dump file and that of our code.

Comment: that won't work.  see my enhanced answer.  use -g symbols and replicate the bug instead.

Answer (score 7):

A template is only converted into code when you instantiate an instance of that template.  You won't get any asm for a template unless you instantiate it.

However, you can ask the compiler to explicity instantiate instances of a template:

```
template class TemplatedClass<char>;
```

If you place such a line into your c file, you will get asm generated for the `char` variant of your template.

---

**Debugging template code update**

Looks like your real question is - how do I find out what line in my template code my program crashed at?

It sounds like you have a core file, you have pinpointed the address, and looked up the assembly at that address and now want to find out what that assembly means.

Your plan is to recompile the template by itself, and look for a matching stretch of assembler.

**Your solution will not work**

1. templates need to be instantiated for a particular type otherwise they don't compile
2. the code generated will often be different for each type you select in (1)
3. template code is usually compiled multiple times in a program, each time in the compilation unit of the caller of the template functions.
4. due to the above, you will not find an exact match for the crashing assembly code.

**Your solution is not necessary**

I assume you can replicate the crash (i.e. it's not a customer core file you are looking at).

By adding symbols `-g` to the arguments to gcc each time you compile, you will be able to work out what line the program crashed on.

Do that, then make it crash again.

I won't say that template debugging is easy, but it doesn't get any easier than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile a template. As the name suggests a template is incomplete code you need to instantiate it with some type arguments before it can be compiled to machine code.

Try compiling some code that use the template. Depending on the type arguments the generated code can differ.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually use the templated code, compiler is not required to produce anything.